# Memory management and caching content jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

This is driving me crazy.

In the webapp I am creating using jqm, one of the pages has some collapsible blocks with listviews inside which populate dynamically when they are clicked and uncollapsed. The number of elements in each listview is about 500. This becomes a bigger issue given each element has a thumbnail.

When I uncollapsed a new block, I can feel how hard my iphone is working. This is because the memory allocated for the browser gets filled, I assume.

Is there a way to free the memory/cache when a new collapsible block is open? Or can I prevent the data to be mapped to the cache so that I get a little boots in performance?

I am open to any other suggestion.

Edited on 10/13/2011

Here is the code I am using

```
$('div.century').live('expand', function(){
    var idval = $(this).attr('id'); 
    console.log('expanded'+idval);

    $.get("helpers/getByCentury.php", { id: idval},
        function(data){
            $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").html(data);
            $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").listview('refresh');
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the data when the collapsible block is closed then you could bind to the `collapse` event and remove the HTML inside the collapsible at that time:

```
$('div.century').live('expand', function(){
    var idval = $(this).attr('id'); 
    if (typeof(console.log) == 'function') {
        console.log('expanded'+idval);
    }
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    $.get("helpers/getByCentury.php", { id: idval},
        function(data){
            $("#"+idval+" ul.ulist").html(data).listview('refresh');
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        });
}).live('collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('.ulist').find('li').remove();
});
```

I'm kind of guessing as to the structure of your collapsible block so you may need to tweak the selector to remove the proper elements.

Also, I noticed when I tested this that the `collapse` event is fired on page-load.

Comment: Thank.. That worked. Another solution I found is to remove all the children of ulist using $(".classofchildren").remove();  everytime the function is called.

Comment: @jasper i have tried same thing but collapse content are not getting changed .here is my link and  code.plz help  way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/collapse-new2.php  $('div.info').live('expand', function(){var record =$(this).data("record");if (typeof(console.log) == 'function') {
console.log('expanded'+record);}$.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait.";$(".detail", this).load("quotesget5.php?record="+record,
function(data){$("."+info+"ul.check").html(data).listview('refresh');
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();});}).live('collapse', function () {
$(this).find('.check').find('li').remove();});

Comment: @jasper can you plz help

Comment: @Steeve This isn't the correct place to ask a question, for instance you can't format your code to be legible here. Ask a new question and let me know the link to it, I'll see what I see.

Comment: @Jasper regret for that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347464/loading-image-on-dynamically-loading-jquery-mobile-collapsable-content

Answer (score 1):

If you remove elements from the DOM and you clear out references to objects or DOM elements from your javascript, then the memory used by those objects can be reclaimed by the browser via garbage collection.  In javascript, an object will be freed when there are no longer any references to it.

Comment: jfriend thanks for your reply. That is exactly what I want to do. I just don't know how. I posted my code so you have an idea. I don't want to set cache:false or clear cache after execution of the script because I need the elements from the current collapsible list to be cached. I would to do something like remove the elements from the DOM before the script is executed, so that the old space can be used by the new list.