# Destroy cache on dynamically loading jquery mobile collapsable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am loading content on jquery mobile collapsable dynamically and would like to show loading image while contents are being loaded once clicked on other list the previous one to be closed and want to destroy its cache as well so that if again clicked it shows new content as I am loading random content on collapsable.

Here is my code using for loading content dynamically in collapsable:

```
 <script>

$('div.info').live('expand', function(){
    var record = $(this).data("record");
 console.log('expanded '+record);
    $(".detail", this).load("get5.php?record="+record);




    });
  </script>
```

[Live link](http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/collapse-new2.php):

**UPDATE**

```
$('div.info').live('expand', function(){
    var record = $(this).data("record");
    if (typeof(console.log) == 'function') {
        console.log('expanded'+record);
    }
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";
    $(".detail", this).load("quotesget5.php?record="+record, function(data){
        $("."+info+" ul.check").html(data).listview('refresh');
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    });
}).live('collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('.check').find('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the method to show the loading spinner before your AJAX request and then calling the method to hide the loading spinner after the AJAX request (in the request's callback)?

Comment: @i have tried this  <script>

    $('div.info').live('expand', function(){
    var record = $(this).data("record"); 
    if (typeof(console.log) == 'function') {
        console.log('expanded'+record);
    }
  $.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";
        $(".detail", this).load("quotesget5.php?record="+record,
        function(data){
             $("."+info+" ul.check").html(data).listview('refresh');
           $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

  });

}).live('collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('.check').find('li').remove();
});
    
        </script>

Comment: @Jasper i want to refresh the content of collapsable when collapsed and again clocked

Comment: @Jasper can u please help,here is live link http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/collapse-new2.php

Comment: I updated your question with the code that matters... It's important to post proper code in your question, or else how is anyone going to help you? I think you might be misunderstanding the use of callback functions for AJAX requests. What you need to do is call `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` before you create your AJAX request, then call `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` in the callback function. That creates the following flow: 1. You show the loading spinner. 2. You create an AJAX request. 3. When that AJAX request returns, you hide the loading spinner.

Comment: Also, for future knowledge, people are unlikely to follow a link to a site they don't know, I won't in general. So you should copy your code into a site like JSFiddle so that people who want to help you can play with it in a safe environment.

Comment: @Jasper thanks for ur advice. i will follow ur advice